# Calculate the homology of the mapping cone of $\Delta.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

> Let $\Delta : S^n \longrightarrow S^n \times S^ n$ be the diagonal map given by $\Delta (x) = (x,x),$ $x \in S^n.$ Calculate  $H_{*} (C(\Delta)),$ the homology of the mapping cone of $\Delta.$

I have tried to use Mayer-Vietoris sequence to solve the problem but couldn't quite able to do it. Is there any specific way to approach such problems? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris should work.

Comment: @Кряжев Арсений can you please tell me how do you cover $C(\Delta)$ by interior of two sets?

Comment: Cut "a tip" of the cone. You will get two pieces: one is contractible and another equivalent to $S^n \times S^n$. Their intersection is $S^n$.

Comment: @Кряжев Арсений could you please elaborate? I am not comfortable with such coverings.

Answer (score 2):

If you cover the cone $X := C(\Delta)$ as in the picture, you will have $X = int(A) \cup int(B).$ Note that $A$ contracts to a point, $A \cap B$ is homotopically equivalent to $S^n,$ and $B$ deformation-retracts on $S^n \times S^n.$

Thus, for $k \not= 0,n$ we have $H_k(A \cap B) = 0$ and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence looks as follows:

$$\ldots \to 0 \to H_{n+1}(S^n \times S^n)  \to H_{n+1}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_n(S^n) \xrightarrow{\Delta_*} H_n(S^n \times S^n) \to H_n(X) \to 0 \to H_{n-1}(S^n \times S^n) \to H_{n-1}(X) \to 0 \to \ldots$$

Since $\Delta_*$ is injective, $\partial$ is also zero, and thus $H_k(X) \simeq H_k(S^n \times S^n) $ for $k \not= n,$ wheareas $H_n(X)$ is the cokernel of $\Delta_*$.

[Intuitively, you get rid of one of the $n$-holes of $S^n \times S^n$ by glueing a cell along a cycle. It is possible to picture on a torus though I'm not sure how helpful that would be for you. This intuition can of course be made into another formal proof.]

[image]

Comment: I think the only problem arises in computing $H_k (C(\Delta)),$ for $k = n, n+1.$ Is it possible to address these two things? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you use the definition of $\Delta\ $?

Comment: @Fanatics Delta is mentioned twice in my last paragraph (the one after the sequence) and is used only there.

Comment: How do you determine the map $\Delta_*\ $? Will it be $1 \mapsto (1,1)\ $?

Comment: @Fanatics Yes, it will. The cell structure gives it immediately, or the Kunneth formula.

Comment: @Dey $\Delta_*$ is there because the inclusion of light-green area into the yellow area deformation retracts on $\Delta.$ I don't have to work for any more cases, please pay more attention to what's written.

Comment: I don't understand why 1) the light green part deformation retract to $S^n$ (it seems to me that it should deformation retract to disk.) 2) what is wrong in the following?: Intuitively, cone($\Delta$) deformation retracts to $S^n\times S^n$ so $H_*($ cone $(\Delta)$)= $H_*(S^n\times S^n)$? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro (2) The light green part (the intersection $A \cap B$) is literally a product of $S^n$ with a cylinder. (2) If $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and you glue the cone on $X$ to $Y$, then you are trying, intuitively, to collapse the subspace $X$ to a point: $Y \cup CX$ is trying to be homotopy equivalent to $Y / X$. In this particular case, the cone on $\Delta$ is modeling, up to homotopy, $(S^n \times S^n)/\sim$, where you are collapsing the image of $S^n$ under $\Delta$ to a point.